# How can we coerce a mutable reference into an immutable when we can never have both at the same time?

Tags: rust

I don't understand how the third case of `Deref` coercion interacting with mutability is implemented:

> From `&mut T` to `&U` when `T: Deref<Target=U>`

[It states](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-02-deref.html#how-deref-coercion-interacts-with-mutability) (emphasis mine):

> The third case is trickier: Rust will also coerce a mutable reference
> to an immutable one. But the reverse is not possible: immutable
> references will never coerce to mutable references. Because of the
> borrowing rules, if you have a mutable reference, that mutable
> reference must be the only reference to that data (otherwise, the
> program wouldn’t compile). **Converting one mutable reference to one
> immutable reference will never break the borrowing rules.** Converting
> an immutable reference to a mutable reference would require that the
> initial immutable reference is the only immutable reference to that
> data, but the borrowing rules don’t guarantee that. Therefore, Rust
> can’t make the assumption that converting an immutable reference to a
> mutable reference is possible.

The [borrowing rules state](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html#the-rules-of-references):

> At any given time, you can have either one mutable reference or any
> number of immutable references.

How can we coerce a mutable reference into an immutable when we can never have both at the same time? Is there an example? Does this have something to do with liveness?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of those subtleties that's easy to lose when trying to write an informal, readable explanation of the rules. I'll try to explain it as I understand it — but note that I am no expert on the *exact* borrow rules; I just have a working model which I've explained to myself in my own way.

“Converting a mutable reference to an immutable reference” is not quite what is going on here. Rather, you are borrowing (or *“reborrowing”*) the mutable reference. This follows the same rules as an owned object:

- **Given any `T` you can borrow it to obtain an `&'a T`,** where `'a` is a lifetime starting at the use of the `&` operator.

If we let the type variable `T` be `&'b mut U` (`'b` being whatever lifetime the mutable reference started with) then we substitute it in and obtain

- **Given any `&'b mut U` you can borrow it to obtain an `&'a &'b mut U`,** where `'a` is a lifetime starting at the use of the `&` operator.

(In reality we don't always construct this double reference — the very rule you're asking for bypasses it — but I'm using it as a tool to explain what's going on.)

In general, when you borrow an owned `T`, you can't mutate the `T` directly until the borrow ends. The exact same principle applies to reborrowing a reference: if you have an `&'b mut U` and you borrow it, you *can't mutate the `&'b mut U` until the borrow ends.* Thus, for the lifetime `'a` of the immutable reference, the mutable reference *cannot be used to mutate the `U`*. Mutable aliasing is prohibited.

The text “At any given time, you can have either one mutable reference or any number of immutable references.” should be understood as reading “…references *to the same value” — a reference is not the same value as its referent.* If you write

```rust
let x = 1;
let b = &mut x;
let a = &b;  // or &*b, or coercion — all produce the same lifetimes
```

then `x` is borrowed by `b`, so can only be mutated through `b`, and `b` is borrowed immutably by `a`, so *neither `b` nor `x`* can actually be used to mutate anything until `a` is dropped.

The reason I say that this is *reborrowing* and not *converting* is because `a` has a lifetime that is *separate* from `b`'s.

Comment: One interesting consequence of this fact: "`&mut T` is `Sync` (if `T` is `Sync`) [...] a mutable reference behind a shared reference (that is, `& &mut T`) becomes read-only, as if it were a `& &T`. Hence there is no risk of a data race." -- from the docs for the [`Sync` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Sync.html)

Comment: I can’t tell if this is officially re-borrowing or a side effect of liveness - or both concepts are entangled. Liveness being that a borrows is only invalid in case where the violation involves live references. I learned about that here https://youtu.be/_agDeiWek8w afterwards.